# Firebase ValueEventListener When Data Is Retrieved

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I use firebase database and I set a ValueEventListener for the database reference. Is there a function you can override that is called when the data is retrieved?

```
public void getMarkedOrUnmarkedAsDone() {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(uID)
            .child("sak_1")
            .child("steg_1")
            .child("marked_as_done");

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            loadingSpinner = true;

            Toast.makeText(ToDoList.this, "Getting data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().equals("true")) {

                markedAsDone = true;

            } else {

                markedAsDone = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No, there is not. Please check the duplicate to see why.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the data is retrieved"? The `onDataChange` method will be called every time data is retrieved.